# SMS Service in asp.net web application using GSM Modem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sms

I am developing a web application in asp.net in which i want to send sms on mobile phones using GSM Modem. For this purpose I need some help or API for sending sms. If anyone have such experience in this field then kindly share with me and provide me some tutorial links or personal help.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I've used:

[GSMComm](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm)

And the commercial product:

[MessagingToolkit](http://twit88.com/platform/projects/show/messagingtoolkit)

Both worked reasonably well.

Comment: dear i am using mobile phone for sending sms instead of GSM Modem then please tell me what is Port, Baudrate, SMSC?

Comment: @BilalAsghar Your original post says "...using GSM Modem".  These settings are all dependent on your device and how it is recognized or installed on the OS.  Consult the manufacturer's and provider's documentation.

Comment: dear can you tell me how u integrate it with your software because these software are in .exe or in .msi format. How i can connect it with my web.

Answer (score 0):

Use an SMS gateway software which will provide you an HTTP interface for communicating with the SMS carrier medium. For the applications it is easier to interact using the application layer protocols like HTTP instead of going into the details of the SMS protocols. Refer to the following post for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8034756/676803