# Send SMS through application

Tags: java, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Is it possible to send SMS from a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824694/java-is-it-possible-to-send-sms-from-a-java-application)

I need to develop a Java (J2SE/desktop) application which will send SMS. I searched a lot on Google. but didn't find any helpful material regarding this except this, it need some gateway. But that gateway need to purchase.

Is there any way to use free gateway to send message? Please refer Java API used for sending SMS.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to use free gateway to send message?

I doubt it.  SMS's are relatively expensive and nobody is likely to let you send them at their expense.

> Please refer Java API used for sending SMS.

There is no standard Java API for sending SMS's ... but the linked question has some 3rd party solutions.

Answer (score 0):

At work I used Kannel
http://www.kannel.org/

It works fine but I don't think you can send sms for free like Stephen C said.